# What is the best way to play the same sound many times simultaneously on WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, audio

My task is to voice automatic weapons. The problem is that fire sounds are much longer than the distance between shots, so I have to play them simultaneously. I came up with this code below, but first shots are buggy and loading sound as new every time doesn't look like a great solution (I cleared all not-sound relative logic):

Please drop me a hint on a better approach.

Thanks

```
public class MachineGun
    {
        private readonly Uri soundLocation
        private readonly int firePeriod;
        private int ticksFromLastFire;

        public MachineGun()
        {
            var appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            soundLocation = new Uri("file:///" + appDirectory + @"/Assets\Sounds\GunSounds\fire_MachineGun.wav");
            firePeriod = 3;
            ticksFromLastFire = 0;
        }

        public override void Fire()
        {
            if (ticksFromLastFire < firePeriod) return;
            ticksFromLastFire = 0;

            var sound = new MediaPlayer();
            sound.Open(soundLocation));
            sound.Play();
        }

        public override void IncrementTick() => ticksFromLastFire++;
}
```

Comment: Play the sounds in a loop?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  sound.Play(); }